# ASP.NET Core 2.1 - Request.Path is empty on production machine

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm developing a small calculator with ASP.NET Core 2.1. It works pretty well on my development machine with ISS Express, but when I publish it to the server there seems to be a problem with the variable `Context.Request.Path` - it's empty while noticed that `Context.Request.PathBase` isn't.

Unfortunately `Context.Request.PathBase` is empty on the development machine so I cannot use this.

What's the problem here?

My `Configure` method from `Startup.cs`

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UsePathBase("/Eleganza");
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        var options = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>();
        app.UseRequestLocalization(options.Value);

        //app.UseCookiePolicy();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
}
```

And the partial where I use the variable

```
<div title="@Localizer["language"]: @requestCulture?.Provider?.GetType().Name">
<form id="selectLanguage" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="SetLanguage" asp-route-returnUrl="@Context.Request.Path" method="post" class="form-inline" role="form">
    @Localizer["language"]: <select class="form-control" name="culture" asp-for="@requestCulture.RequestCulture.UICulture.Name" asp-items="cultureItems" onchange="submitForm();"></select>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function submitForm() {
        $('#selectLanguage').submit();
    }
</script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems when you set a base path the Request.Path will contain only parts of the path after the base path.

https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/1178#issuecomment-404883599

> After further testing it appears that PathBase contains just the first
> part of the path after the host. Path contains any additional portion
> of the path after PathBase. For clarity, I've illustrated below;
>
> Url: https://somesite.com/path1/path2/path3
> PathBase: /path1
> Path:
> /path2/path3
>
> This is confusing - Path should include the entire path after the
> host.

Also might be related to https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/49b447d6265f0de44304b1b887cbdd3227cb038d/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions/Extensions/UsePathBaseMiddleware.cs#L54